# how to join to different levels of a date dimension in a data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a simple data warehouse with an existing data mart.  This data mart includes a date dimension table.  Because the date grain of the fact table is day, then the date dimension table is also at the grain of day (i.e., 1 row per day).  Because date is a hierarchical dimension, I have de-normalized the hierarchy into the date dimension table.  So, even though the grain of the date dimension table is day, it also includes attributes like week, month, and year.

I have a new data mart that I'm designing whose fact table date grain is month.  So, I have to join to a month dimension from this new fact table.  What is the best implementation of this month dimension?  That is, should it be a view using the date dimension table?  Or, should it be its own physical table?

Comment: The new data mart should be its own table, with the month and year attributes.

Comment: If the *month dimension* consists only of the attributes *month* and *year* you may find that there is no need for the dimension at all ...